# iOS: How to dynamically add image to a parent view?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I've got a main image on the screen, and have an "overlay" UIView placed on top of it with the background color set to Clear Color.  I want to dynamically place other images inside the overlay view as follows:

```
UIImage* m_icon = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"icon.png"]; 
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:m_icon];
[m_OverlayView addSubview:imageView];
```

But the icon image isn't showing up.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
NSString *icon_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"icon" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage* m_icon = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:icon_path]; 
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:m_icon];
[m_OverlayView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks for the super-fast response!