# How to dynamically change an image in an Image View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

Basically, I have a main UIImageView which I then programmatically add another Image View (with image) on top. What I would like to do is dynamically swap out the image on click, but when I attempt to do so the image does not show. 
Here's what I've implemented so far:

In Storyboard:    //mainImgView

[image]

In.h:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
     @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *overlayImgView;
@end
```

In.m:

```
-(IBAction) addOverlayImgViewWImgToMainImgView:(UIButton *)sender{    
    UIImage *tempImg1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"xcode_icon.png"];

    self.overlayImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:tempImg1];
    [mainImgView addSubview:self.overlayImgView];   
}

-(IBAction) swapImg:(UIButton *)sender{
    UIImage *tempImg2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"another_icon.png"];
    [self.overlayImgView setImage:tempImg2];
}
```

If someone could please shed some light on what I’m doing wrong, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Among the links I've looked at are:

[iOS: How to dynamically add image to a parent view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571075/ios-how-to-dynamically-add-image-to-a-parent-view)

[UIImage imageNamed returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998544/uiimage-imagenamed-returns-nil/10998746#10998746)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImageView/initWithImage:

Additional Info:

There's already an image on the main Image View and I'm adding a smaller (50x50) Image View (w/ image) to it. When I try to swap it out, the current image is disappearing then replace with a white box.

The image files are 50x50 and are in my 'Supported Files' folder. I do not have a second '@2X' image.

Comment: Why not just set the mainImageView image?  (Instead of adding an overlay)?  Or am I misunderstanding your question...

Comment: Its already set with another image (and I'm overlaying it with another). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
- (IBAction)swapImg:(UIButton *)sender{
    UIImage *tempImg2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"another_icon.png"];
    self.mainImgView.image = tempImg2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the current image still just disappears and the new image (tempImg2) does not appear.

Comment: Actually, tried it with another image, did a clean/build, and added '@2x' and worked. Your method works as well.